# How to compare "trend" between two groups

Tags: r, percentage, trend

I'd like to consult with you which statistical method I should use for the following study. (This is JUST AN EXAMPLE, thank you) The research hypothesis is that the proportion of male students increases with grade. At first, I investigated City A, and found that the proportions of male students in primary school, high school, and college are 30%, 50%, and 70%, respectively. Then I did this in City B, and got similar results: 31%, 51%, and 71%, respectively. Now, I'd like to write in my paper that the "trend" (proportion of males increases with grade) is not significantly different between City A and City B. What statistical method should I use? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moderated regression (IV: grade DV: proportion of males, moderator: City).